# Redux: Import new reducers and feed them new state on route change

Tags: redux, react-boilerplate

### The goal

I want to change reducers (and feed them new state) when the route changes.

### Current Attempt

I have a route set up with a slug (`/components/:slug`) that is handled by my `ComponentPage` reducer. This reducer notices that the route changed (via Redux-saga) and has an opportunity to fetch state that's relevant to the current `:slug`.

When the router first updates to go to a `/components` page, the state looks something like this:

```
route: {...}
language: {...}
theme: {...}
componentPage: {
  content: {[default / empty]}
}
```

After `ComponentPage` fetches data related to the `:slug`, it looks something like this:

```
route: {...}
language: {...}
theme: {...}
componentPage: {
  content: {...}
  liveExample: {...}
  tabCollection: {...}
}
```

In the above state tree, items like `liveExample` and `tabCollection` represent new domains that are managed by their own reducers (and have their initial state set by `componentPageReducer`).

My intention is that items like these will be set dynamically by `ComponentPage` based on the page's `:slug` so that they can be swapped out for other components without littering the state tree with every possible component that could go on every possible instance of a component page.

### The issue

I currently have configuration files set up to import the specific reducers each page needs so that they can feed them to `ComponentPage` based on the `:slug`. Unfortunately, my current method of implementation only suffices to care for the initial render—after that pass-through, the imported reducers are replaced by the objects they return.

#### An example of an object I'm currently handing to `ComponentPage`

```
pageConfiguration = {
  content: {...},
  liveExample: (state, action) => liveExampleReducer(state || liveExampleConfiguration, action),
  tabCollection: (state, action) => tabCollectionReducer(state || tabCollectionConfiguration, action),
}
```

**A note on how I came to this**:

Redux's `combineReducers` would return something of this structure:

```
liveExample: liveExampleReducer(liveExampleConfiguration, action),
tabCollection: tabCollectionReducer(tabCollectionConfiguration, action),
```

That would be ideal (if I just knew how to get these listed as proper reducers). Instead, I had to make the function callable so that I could pass in the `action` (when `componentPageReducer` doesn't match an `action.type`, it still tries to call these dynamically loaded reducers manually, as you'll see below). (They also accept `state || configuration` so that when these get called subsequent times, they don't keep reinitializing with configuration/initial data).

#### ComponentPage/reducer.js

```
export default function componentPageReducer(state = initialState, action) {
  switch (action.type) {
    case FETCH_SLUG:
      // gets the `pageConfiguration` object from above,
      // and generates the state by manually mapping through
      // its functions and calling them
      if (pages.has(action.payload.slug)) {
        return pages.get(action.payload.slug).map((x) => {
          if (typeof x === 'function') {
            return x(undefined, action)
          }
          return x
        })
      }
      return state
    default:
      // an attempt at calling the now-nonexistent
      // imported reducer functions
      return state.map((x) => {
        if (typeof x === 'function') {
          return x(state, action)
        }
        return x
      })
  }
}
```

### Possible solutions

So, from what I can tell, this *might* work if I store the reducer functions themselves in the state and map their `return` value onto a different key so they don't replace themselves, but... **it seems like I'm going down a weird road here**.

I think that I am currently hacking together something that *probably shouldn't be considered proper Reducer Composition*. I don't know if there is a more elegant way to handle this sort of scenario.

Answer (score 1):

The standard approach to dynamic reducer slices is to keep around an object of all the existing slice reducers, and when you need to add a new one at runtime, update that object and re-run `combineReducers.  To give you the basic idea:

```
let sliceReducers = {
    first : firstReducer,
    second : secondReducer
};

const initialRootReducer = combineReducers(sliceReducers);
const store = createStore(initialRootReducer);


// sometime later

sliceReducers = {
    ...sliceReducers,
    third : thirdReducer
}

const newRootReducer = combineReducers(sliceReducers);
store.replaceReducer(newRootReducer);
```

I have a couple articles on the topic in the [Redux Techniques#Reducers](https://github.com/markerikson/react-redux-links/blob/master/redux-techniques.md#reducers) section of my [React/Redux links list](https://github.com/markerikson/react-redux-links).  You may also want to look at the [`injectAsyncReducer`](https://github.com/react-boilerplate/react-boilerplate/blob/a09fb22ff591a71d67ee4bb7a45f2f9aee09deee/app/utils/asyncInjectors.js#L32-L46) utility from the React-Boilerplate toolkit.